# PyQt5: How to change fonts-style within imported font-family?

Tags: css, pyqt5, google-font-api

From https://fonts.google.com/, I downloaded the "Kanit" font package. From this package, I want to use multiple fonts, such as Kanit-Light and Kanit-SemiBold. With the following lines, the fonts are included in the application:

```
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('styles/fonts/Kanit/Kanit-Light.ttf')
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('styles/fonts/Kanit/Kanit-SemiBold.ttf')
```

With `QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies` I can check my fonts and I can see they are imported correctly: `'Kanit Light', 'Kanit SemiBold'`
In my styles.css file, I select the font with: `font-family: Kanit;`. This works fine when only one font-style within the same family is imported. However, when importing multiple font-styles, only the last added font is actually used in the application (in my case: SemiBold). How can I change between the fonts within a font-family?

I tried the following things (which were unsuccessful):

- `font-family: Kanit, Kanit Light;` (with and without dash)
- `font-family: Kanit; font: Light;`
- `font-family: Kanit; font: Kanit Light;` (with and without dash)
- `font-family: Kanit; font-style: Light;`
- `font-family: Kanit; font-style: Kanit Light;` (with and without dash)

Comment: Did you try `font-family: "Kanit Light";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `font-family: Kanit;` in your CSS. The downloaded fonts-styles (light & semibold in my case) have some properties (font-size, font-weight) that you can now access. For example, Kanit-Light enables access to `font-weight: 100;`, whereas SemiBold enables access to `font-weight: 600;`. For the Kanit font I use, you can find this info at: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kanit?query=kanit